# Download image of currently rendered map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on an application that is using the google maps javascript API and it seems like it would be good to be able to download screenshots of the currently rendered map in our application.

I can't seem to find any options in the api that describe how to do this.

Is there anyway to download an image of the currently rendered map? Currently we are using a `HYBRID` map type

Comment: It's not allowed! see the terms: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_tiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an option in the Javascript API.  However you might be able to achieve the same map using the Static maps API, which just generates a PNG image: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: I'm not trying to be a pain but, if we are to go by the exact wording of the terms then the answer might depend on what you intend to do with the image. see: https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_staticmaps_reuse and https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_screenshots